# AWS login details in a account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

In AWS for monitoring purposes, I need to find a list of all users' login details for the past week in an AWS account. So how can I acquire it?

Comment: Are you wanting to know _every_ login, or just when they last logged in?

Answer (score 1):

From [Viewing last accessed information for IAM - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_access-advisor-view-data.html):

> You can view last accessed information for IAM on the **Access Advisor tab in the IAM console**.
>
> **For Users:** View the list of services that the user can access. You can also **view when they last accessed the service**, and what policies they used. Choose the name of the policy to learn whether it is a managed policy, an inline user policy, or an inline policy for the user group.